# How to check if there was any RuntimeError in subprocess in python?

Tags: python

I am able to catch it with subprocess.CalledProcessError, however I want to ensure that there it was RuntimeError. I am using "subprocess.check_call" method.

I tried something like this and it didn't work.

```
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(arguments, cwd=<my_cwd>)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        try:
            raise
        except RuntimeError:
            print "Runtime Error....."
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do what you want. Look at the description of the `check_call` method.

> Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete.  If
>       the exit code was zero then return, otherwise raise
>       CalledProcessError.  The CalledProcessError object will have the
>       return code in the returncode attribute. 
>       The arguments are the same as for the call function. 
>       Example:
>       `check_call(["ls", "-l"])`

If you are calling a python script using `subprocess.check_call` you can't tell if a `RuntimeError` occurred since the only thing that matters is the return code of the script.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do what you're asking.  They are separate processes. The parent can't catch any exceptions raised by the child. The `CalledProcessError` you're able to catch is raised by `check_call` in the parent itself, after examining the exit status of the child.